# Are all IVP's and BVP´s essentially eigenvalue/eigenfunctions problems?

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Are all IVP's and BVP´s essentially eigenvalue/eigenfunctions problems, or does there exist some IVP or BVP which is not of this "nature"? (By "essentiell" I mean "can be regarded as")

Comment: True for linear differential operator.

Comment: @CheeHan do you have a counterexampel and how would you formulate the essentiell nature of this problem?

Comment: The way I see eigenvalue problems is that they stem out from linear operator, that is also how we first being introduced the theory of eigenvalue-eigenvector in a linear algebra course. However, we can also have a nonlinear eigenvalue problem, see this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonlinear_eigenproblem but I am not too familiar with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the problem contains some of the conditions of the form e.g. $u_x(a,t)=f(t)u(a,t)$ , it cannot be solved by just considering the usual eigenvalue/eigenfunctions problems.

Comment: something similar to this I suppose...https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burgers'_equation